# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Tags: java, json, exception, mobile, codenameone

I'm working on CodeName One and I've got this error while retrieving data from the database.

The problem is with the element with type date
the json response is working well and other attributes are displayed successfully.

Here's my code and I hope that someone could help me. Thank you in advance.

```java
private Concour parseConcours(Map<String, Object> map) {
  Concour c = new Concour();

  c.setId(((Double) map.get("id")).intValue());
  c.setSujet(map.get("sujet").toString());
  c.setNom(map.get("nom").toString());
  c.setImageName(map.get("imageName").toString());
  c.setDescription(map.get("description").toString());
  c.setCategorie(map.get("categorie").toString());
  c.setCouleur(map.get("couleur").toString());
  c.setDateDebut(new Date((((Double) ((Map<String, Object>) map.get("dateDebut")).get("timestamp")).longValue() * 1000)));
  c.setDateFin(new Date((((Double) ((Map<String, Object>) map.get("dateFin")).get("timestamp")).longValue() * 1000)));

  return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
try {
   Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(sDate1); 
   c.setDateDebut(date1); 
    } 
catch (ParseException ex) { 
     System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hyy what you can do is convert date string which you got from map to simpledateformat and then assign it in setter method as given below.

```
c.setDateDebut(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(map.get("dateDebut")));
c.setDateFin(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(map.get("dateFin")));
```

Comment: thank you for your response but it still not working

Comment: What isn't working? The response seems correct. Do you get a different exception?

Answer (score 0):

probleme resolved with switching to this lines:

```
                try {
                    Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(sDate1);
                    c.setDateDebut(date1);
                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
```